# Martingale Conceptual Question

Tags: probability-theory

For a normal random walk where $Y_i = \pm\frac{1}{2}$ with equal probability and $X_i = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$, my book says the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a martingale is written as $\sigma(X_0, X_1, X_2, \ldots X_n)$.  Is this different than the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_n$?  Is it just the union of all of the $\sigma$-algebras for $X_0, \ldots X_n$?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- The union of the $\sigma$-algebras has no reason to be a $\sigma$-algebra; $\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by these unions.
- Take $n=2$. Then $X_2$ can take the values $1$ on the set $A_1:=\{Y_1=1/2\}\cap \{Y_2=1/2\}$, $0$ on  $A_0:=(\{Y_1=1/2\}\cap \{Y_2=-1/2\})\cup(\{Y_1=-1/2\}\cap \{Y_2=1/2\})$ and $-1$ on $A_{-1}=\{Y_1=-1/2\}\cap \{Y_2=-1/2\}$, from which we deduce that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_2$ is actually generated by the partition $\{A_1,A_0,A_{-1}\}$ and these sets are not measurable with respect to $\sigma(X_1)$.